# Setting Up ReactJs.net?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, reactjs, react-native

I am using VS 2015 and am using reactjs.net. I don't see many tutorials on reactjs.net so I found [this sample code](https://github.com/buckyroberts/React-Redux-Boilerplate) and trying to use the exact same code in my reactjs.net project.

However it does not seem to like when I use ".js" files nor does it like my ecma6 stuff like import/export.

What do I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment [here](http://reactjs.net/guides/es6.html?fb_comment_id=696931800387622_995498833864249#f126d850f5dd28c), you will need to setup and run webpack to take advantage of import/export.. in my experience it's better to just use react without reactjs.net, unless you are specifically looking for server-side rendering. And unless you are specifically concerned about SEO, server-side rendering is usually too much hassle to be worth the trouble.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to use reactjs.net is because I want to leverage mvc owin as I am planning to use oauth.

Comment: Ah ok according to the blog Daniel is trying to make reactjs.net play nicely with OWIN.. unfortunately I am not very familiar with OWIN so I can't speak to it, however I don't think that OWIN would preclude using React on it's own without ReactJS.net.

Comment: What blog post? I might try react without reactjs and when I get to authentication I guess figure it out then.